# How to comment in a user post with Senium on Instagram?

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I'm using Selenium library on Python and I have developed a code that made typical Instagram human actions.

BUT this one I'm telling you is impossible, it's like instagram banned this.

Im trying to comment on a user's photo, like accessing @Cristiano posts and comment on them. I can reach this accessing posts by hashtag but in a user profile it's impossible.

Can somebody help me?

I tried with:

```
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div/form").click()
        commentbox = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form/textarea")


        commentbox.send_keys('FOLLOW ME')
        commentbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

While I'm with the first post of a profile opened.

Comment: Did you try to check which part of the page is found by `.find_element`? Did you try to come up with a more specific way to look for the parts you want? It seems like the plan is to find just *whatever* form *happens to be* on the page. Maybe there's another one that isn't the one you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it with this:

```
        comm = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/div[1]/div[1]/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea')
        comm.click()
        Wait(2,5)
        txtarea = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/div[1]/div[1]/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea')                                   
        Wait(2,5)   

        txtarea.send_keys('FOLLOW ME')
        Wait(3,5)
        txtarea.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```